# DKIM signature in swift mailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer, dkim

I'm trying to set a DKIM header using swift mailer.
The issue is that when I inspect the email in Gmail the DKIM status is 'FAIL'.
According to https://mxtoolbox.com and few other tools the TXT record for DKIM is correct. The SPF and DMARC records are OK (even for Gmail).

Here's the part of the code where I set the

```
$privateKey = file_get_contents('/path/to/the/private.key');
$domainName = 'mydomain.name';
$selector = 'default';
$signer = new Swift_Signers_DKIMSigner($privateKey, $domainName, $selector);

$swift_message = Swift_SignedMessage::newInstance();
$swift_message->attachSigner($signer);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It came out that I need to ignore the 'Return-Path' header and one custom header that I've added when I do the DKIM signature

```
$signer->ignoreHeader('MyTrackingID');
$signer->ignoreHeader('Return-Path');
```

There's a lot of useful information on that topic here:

https://help.returnpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/222438487-DKIM-signature-header-detail

Comment: Adding a return-path header at the origin of a message is an RFC contravention; it should not be there in the first place. The return path header should be added *by the receiver*, populated from the address submitted in the `MAIL FROM` SMTP command that delivered the message.